# How can I login in amazon mws with third party app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-marketplace

I am working on Web app that will manage inventory, Orders, Shipments using Amazon MWS api.

A seller can register in the app and can connect to Amazon MWS api, I am able to do with provided `Marketplace_Id`, `Seller_Id`, `Access_Key_ID`, `Secret_Access_Key` keys but I don't want to do like entering all the keys public.

I am using ready-made laravel package to access all the MWS APIs. To access seller account it requires `Marketplace_Id`, `Seller_Id`, `Access_Key_ID`, `Secret_Access_Key`.

I have checked some platforms like AMZPing, Inventory Lab. They provides just one like to connect to Amazon MWS, using that link sellers are able to connect to Amazon MWS.

Here it the link to connect amazon MWS.

**AMZPing:**

```
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/registration/register.html?
id=5ccea641-5bec-1234-1234-c123490628df&
returnPathAndParameters=/Account/HandleReturnURLForMWS?userId=12124&email=test%40gmail.com&
SignatureVersion=2&
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&
AWSAccessKeyId=ABSEDGDUSKXHEYWTDGSANDBDBD&
Signature=h1MXM5FiioxWY6ATwCgPtdbI1ADSWDETDDN6B/SWQAFR=
```

**Inventory Lab:**

```
https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/mws/registration/register.html?
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&
SignatureVersion=2&
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJWMONWSHDEUJ2OVA&
id=9583ded2-ad36-1234-1234-122096397fd6&
returnPathAndParameters=/webhook?id=1984&region=NA&env=production&
Signature=txLrXJ%2BUvYlmeq8gFu4atByFTBq89UKb2MorK1uaeyg=
```

How can I connect like the above link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is MWS service- IRP, It is not readily available to everyone. You have to contact MWS Support and convince them to set you up for it .

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I contacted with MWS support and they said that currently not supporting creation of new IRPs

Comment: @PankajMakwana Can you please let me know how you achieved the IRP?

Comment: @MahakChoudhary sorry still not done, so left it